# How fast should I clock my CPLD as compared to my SPI bus' speed?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock

As I'm sure everyone here knows, in FPGA/CPLD design one often needs to synchronize a slower asynchronous signal (say, the SCK line of SPI) with a much faster clock signal thats directly fed to the FPGA/CPLD. **My question is, how much faster does the FPGA/CPLD clock needs to be relative to my asynchronous signal? Ten times? Twenty times?**

In my case less than 10x doesn't work well. Specifically: I set my SCK speed to 4 MHz whereas my clock was 20 MHz. This didn't work at all. 2 Mhz works, but occasionally I get some problems. At 1 MHz, it works very well - no issues so far.

VHDL Code for the CPLD:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PISO is
  port(CLK, nCS, SCK, nRESET : in std_logic;
                PI  : in  std_logic_vector(71 downto 0);
                SO  : out std_logic);
end PISO;


architecture archi of PISO is
   signal tmp: std_logic_vector(PI'high downto PI'low);
   signal bitOut: std_logic;
   signal rise, fall : std_logic;
   signal oscena:   std_logic;
   signal iCLK  :   std_logic;

   signal SCK_rising, SCK_falling, SCK_sync, SCK_delay : std_logic;
   signal CS_rising, CS_falling, CS_sync, CS_delay     : std_logic;

   component sync
    generic(
        RESET_STATE : std_logic := '0' -- '0' for active low sync
    );
    port(
        clk  : in  std_logic;
        rstN : in  std_logic;
        d    : in  std_logic;
        q    : out std_logic
    );
end component;

   begin
    sync1 : sync
    generic map(
        RESET_STATE => '0'
    )
    port map(
        clk  => clk,
        rstN => nRESET,
        d    => sck,
        q    => SCK_sync
    );

sync2 : sync
    generic map(
        RESET_STATE => '1'
    )
    port map(
        clk  => clk,
        rstN => nRESET,
        d    => nCS,
        q    => CS_sync
    );

    process(clk, nRESET)
begin
    if (nRESET = '0') then
        sck_rising  <= '0';
        sck_falling <= '0';
        sck_delay   <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        if cs_sync = '1' then
            sck_delay   <= '0';
            sck_rising  <= '0';
            sck_falling <= '0';
        else
            sck_delay   <= sck_sync;
            sck_rising  <= sck_sync and (not sck_delay);
            sck_falling <= (not sck_sync) and sck_delay;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

process(clk, nRESET)
begin
    if (nRESET = '0') then
        cs_rising  <= '0';
        cs_falling <= '0';
        cs_delay   <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        cs_delay   <= cs_sync;
        cs_rising  <= cs_sync and (not cs_delay);
        cs_falling <= (not cs_sync) and cs_delay;
    end if;
end process;


process(CLK, nRESET)
begin
    if (nRESET = '0') then
        tmp <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        if CS_sync = '0' then
            if SCK_falling = '1' then
                tmp <= tmp(PI'high -1 downto PI'low) & '0';
            end if;
        elsif CS_sync = '1' then
            tmp <= PI;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

SO <= tmp(PI'high) when nCS = '0' else 'Z';


end archi;
```

And here's the code for the sync component:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sync is
generic (
    RESET_STATE : std_logic := '0' -- '0' for active low sync
);
port (
    clk   : in  std_logic;
    rstN  : in  std_logic;
    d     : in  std_logic;
    q     : out std_logic
);
end entity;

architecture behavioral of sync is
    signal d_meta : std_logic;
    begin
process(clk, rstN)
begin
    if (rstN = '0') then
        d_meta <= RESET_STATE;
        q      <= RESET_STATE;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        d_meta <= d;
        q      <= d_meta;
    end if;
end process;
end architecture;
```

Regarding simplicity, I know SPI is super simple but I'm a newbie so all of this is rather difficult for me. Only after weeks did it make sense to me that I do need to sync. the signals in the CPLD/FPGA (initially I was just using the SCK as my clock and didn't even have a separate clock on my board. It worked fine for slower speeds but increasing the speed to even 1 MHz made the naiveness of my approach obvious). I'm sure (infact, I know because of your excellent posts around here) your approach is much simpler and more elegant, the issue is that I'll need to get my head around it first because as of now it just sounds like greek to me!

Comment: What's the SCK's pulse width?

Comment: @stevenvh By pulse width, I assume you mean the length of time where the SCK is high? I believe that's half of the time period, so about 0.25 uS if my math is right. I'll measure it tomorrow at work and update here.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that clock frequency isn't everything. If your clock is 1MHz that's 1us period. So sampling at 10MHz would give you 10 samples over that, ideally 5 high and 5 low. If your clock produces only narrow pulses, say 100ns, that may be perfectly within specs (probably, since you're allowed to clock it much faster), but you'll only have 1 sample at 10MHz. So there's a chance of missing that one.

Comment: I'm not sure what's naive about using SCK as a clock inside the CPLD, unless it's something CPLD-specific.  FPGAs can have multiple clock domains inside.  Was the clock trace suffering from transmission-line reflections, or was it too slow, or something else?

Comment: @ajs410 I was told that async. design is a Bad Thing in the FPGA/CPLD world and it's better if I sycned my signals with an external clock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are so many things in this question that it is difficult to know where to start.

I am assuming that your FPGA logic is a SPI slave, not a master.  If it is a master then you have a whole different set of issues which I'm going to avoid going into right now.

The simple direct answer to your question is that you need to sample an async signal at least two times the frequency of your signal.  So if you have a 4 MHz clock then you need to sample it at 8 MHz or higher.  Of course, nothing is simple or direct in this case.

You have things a little more difficult because you are not sampling one async signal, you are sampling three (CLK, CS, and MOSI).  You also need to keep those three signals time-aligned with each other through the sampling process.  And you have to spit out MISO in such a way as to not violate your setup/hold time at the master.

None of this is easy, but having a higher speed clock will make things much easier.  How much higher depends on your code, and you didn't post your code.  I think that I could write code to do it with an 8x clock, but that is just a guess.  Honestly, however, I think this is the wrong approach.

SPI is a super simple interface, and it would be good if you kept it super simple.  SPI has its own clock, and if you use it as a clock then everything becomes almost easy.  Instead of changing clock domains on the serial SPI interface, change clock domains on the parallel data going in/out of your shift registers.  If you look at those signals carefully you might even realize that you don't need to do anything special, or if you do then it's just a flip-flop per signal.  Then you don't need to have your main clock be higher than your SPI clock.  Your main clock could actually be slower!

I do this on my SPI FPGA/CPLD interfaces and I have no problems running SPI at 30+ MHz, with or without a second clock domain.

Comment: "at least two times the frequency of your signal". You know that this is not quite correct. I mention in comment a 100ns pulse width at a 1MHz clock. Sampling at 2MHz will likely miss the pulse. You need twice the harmonic required to have a decent signal, amplitude-wise, and edge-wise.

Comment: @stevenvh True, but I wasn't going to worry about the details too much because I went on to say that for this application you probably need 8x, or better yet do something else entirely.

Comment: Or use hardware that will hold the pulse and has to be actively reset so you receive it?

Comment: @Kortuk - That sounded like a good idea, but on second though, what if it clocks on the falling edge? That will have to be accurate. IIRC SPI clocks in and out at opposite edges.

Comment: @stevenvh, or operate in opposite direction(reset sends line high, or just invert the signal for all it matters). I am just saying if there is a certain signal you are looking for something like this can help.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, I like the idea, but have you read the last sentence I added to my previous comment?

Comment: @stevenvh ha, i misread it actually. You could still use this with two separate buffers but in this case you really have many other issues if SPI is clocking data to/from you at half your system frequency

Comment: Personally I find it easier to make the FPGA/CPLD the SPI master, it avoids synchronization problems entirely if you use an SCK derived from the system clock.

Comment: @ajs410: It's generally easier for a device to be SPI master than slave, but *some* device has to be the slave, and having the SPI take on that role may be easier than having someone else do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, if practical, an SPI slave should have registers that are clocked from the SPI pins.  Those registers, or signals that derive from them, should then be double-synchronized with other logic.  Depending upon application requirements, signals from the other logic may either be double synchronized to the SPI clock or may be fed to the SPI's data output asynchronously (if the SPI data is going to be fed to a single data path which contains at least two latches before it splits, and if the application won't care whether an attempt to read something at the moment it changes yields high or low, async reporting may be just fine).

Even if one doesn't want to design an entire SPI slave interface to be SPI-clocked, one can still have a few key aspects of it clocked from the SPI wires.  At minimum, I would suggest that the SPI clock wire should trigger a latch for the data and a toggle latch.  Pass the data latch through one more level of synchronization than the toggle latch, and then assume that any time the toggle latch value differs from the previous one, new data exists on the clock wire.  Some extra latching logic on the chip-select wire would allow reliable detection of short unselect/reselect events.

PS--Depending upon how the logic and software protocol are designed, it may be possible to have an SPI slave device work reliably even if the attached logic likes to sleep when idle and doesn't wake up "instantly".  Such behavior could not be implemented if everything on the SPI bus had to be synchronized to the main-logic clock (which wouldn't be running while the device was asleep).

PPS--If you really want to run everything synchronous with some "main" clock, you should figure that the setup and hold times of the incoming SPI data will be increased by at least one period of your master clock, and the outgoing data will be delayed by an unpredictable amount which may be anything from zero up to one period of your master clock.  Your master clock needs to be fast enough that you can add a full master-clock period to your timing uncertainties without violating your timing constraints anywhere.  If your allowable timing slop is 1/4 of your SPI clock period, your master clock needs to be more than 4x your SPI clock.  If your allowable timing slop is 1/16 of your SPI clock period, your master clock needs to be more than 16x your SPI clock.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to use the SPI clock to handle the SPI shift register is correct and saves you the bother of trying to oversample properly. One gotcha is in how you transfer that parallel register into another domain. DO NOT use a simple two stage FF synchronizer for each bit as you would for a solitary signal. If you use the FF synchronizers there is a real risk of invalid data clocking in the target domain due to skew or metastability on some bits. The paired FFs only make the probability of metastability exceedingly low but not zero. Assume it will happen.

Parallel busses need to be transferred across domains with a handshake synchronizer. For a fully-synchronous design that can be analyzed with static timing tools the four-phase handshake protocol is the best to use. In this protocol you have a pair of data-valid and ack signals that handshake across domains and guarantee that the bus is stable while the target domain clocks it in.

One exception to this rule is if you have a Gray encoded counter. Because only one bit transitions per count you can send it across domains with the simpler paired FFs.

Comment: The normal danger with using a two-stage FF for each bit is that some bits may change on an earlier clock than others; I would think that if metastability risk (as opposed to split latching) is unacceptable in that case, it would be equally unacceptable with solitary signals.  On the other hand, I was wondering something: in an FPGA, is there any way of specifying that a signal must be ignored in certain cases?  For example, if there is an input which may change at any time when some condition is true, but the circuit is only "supposed" to care about that signal when the condition is false...

Comment: ...would there be a danger that the FPGA might rewrite things so that transitions on that signal when it wasn't supposed to matter might cause glitches downstream?  For example, given the equation `Q := (Q and not E) or (D and E)` [D FF with enable] would there be a danger that a compiler might implement that using a non-hazard-free 3-input mux, such that a transition on D near the clock edge could glitch Q even when synchronous signal E was low?  Is there any nice way to handle such things?

Comment: @supercat For solitary asynchronous control signals the timing is generally loose enough that you can tolerate a one cycle slip. External interfaces must be designed to account for this possibility. If you want to ignore a signal under certain circumstances you just have to gate it (preferably after an initial synchronization stage). Once you have brought external signals into your controlled synchronous domain, the synthesizer can ensure that combinational paths between registers will meet timing. There will be no glitches to deal with if you follow proper synchronous design practices.

Comment: Most programmable logic devices don't implement logic using Boolean primitives, so while there *are* glitches during input transitions you have no way of reliably predicting what they are because you don't know the full implementation details. This is why you set up timing constraints and let the tools verify that the clock period is long enough to account for the longest combinational delay in the design or you make allowances for multi-cycle delays.

Comment: Suppose as a simple example that one has an FPGA which is supposed to read data from an external flash which requires one wait state, and it must take an externally-visible action on the second cycle after it outputs the request to the flash.  It would seem absurd to require an external chip to ensure that the data inputs to the FPGA couldn't change near the first clock edge after the request was issued [since the flash shouldn't care what's on the bus at that time]; what would one have to do to avoid needing to do so?

Comment: One of the things I like about specifying CPLD designs as operations upon flops with sum-of-product equations is that if I compute `myReg.T = Enable & myReg.Q & !Data # Enable & !myReg.Q & Data`, I can know that when `Enable` is low, glitches on "Data" won't affect anything.  What must one do with an FPGA to have such assurance?

Comment: If you're using synchronous I/O with an associated external clock then you don't have to synchronize them first provided that that clock directly drives your input logic and you account for the I/O delays in the timing. The need for synchronizers comes into play when crossing clock domains. Most FPGA applications use a PLL/DLL to multiply an external clock, creating a separate domain that is easiest to treat as asynchronous to the source clock (even if it's phase locked). You either create a small block of logic running off the slow ext. clock or synchronize the ext. clock as if it were data.

Comment: Would you consider an old-fashioned slow memory device which takes more than one clock period to produce valid data "synchronous" or "asynchronous" by that definition?  The data input from such a device might change near some clock edges, but only on those clock edges where nobody should be interested in it.  My main focus is on low-power systems, and I've noticed that ARM-based products often seem to have less flexible peripheral clocking than controllers using other cores, and I'm guessing that it's probably because of synthesis restrictions, but I don't really know.

Comment: Conceptually, I would think that would be ideal in many cases would be a controller whose only system clock option was generated from an internal "as fast as possible" uncalibrated RC oscillator (e.g. 30ish MHz) which was designed to start and stop readily.  To support things like UARTs which need more precise time bases, other time bases (e.g. 4MHz) would be fed into asynchronous graycode counters (e.g. 3 bits) whose outputs would be double-synchronized with the main clock.  The system would compare the synchronized gray-code counter output with a second counter, which would increment...

Comment: ...on any cycle where its value didn't match the double-synchronized output from the other counter.  It would also supply to peripherals a signal indicating the cycles where that second counter was incremented.  Thus, if the async counter was incremented four million times per second, then on four million cycles each second the "Event4Mhz" signal would be high.  With the addition of a little more asynchronous logic to compare the "raw" counter values and force "brief" wake-ups that are just long enough to maintain the 4Mhz peripherals when nothing interesting was happening...

Comment: ...but as soon as something interesting happened be ready to start running code at ~30MHz.  On most parts I've seen, even those supposedly designed for low-power operation, the peripherals and CPU have to use the same time base, which means that cranking up the speed for the CPU will disrupt peripheral timing.  If counters track how many cycles peripherals should have processed from each time base, and how many they actually have, such disruption should be avoidable.